# Can't remove the error with the datetime format in backtrader

Tags: python, backtrader

```
class dataFeed(btfeed.GenericCSVData):
    params = (
        ('dtformat', '%m%d%Y %H:%M:%S'),
        ('datetime', 0),
        ('open', 1),
        ('high', 2),
        ('low', 3),
        ('close', 4),
        ('volume', 5),
        ('openinterest', -1)
    )
```

```
ValueError: time data '12/24/2020 10:00' does not match format '%m%d%Y %H:%M:%S'
```

This is what he time stamp looks like - `12/24/2020  10:00:00 AM`

Comment: Change the dtformat to `'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'` or `'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'`?

Answer (score 0):

Remove slashes from your string:

```
dt_string = dt_string.replace("/", "")
```

or change `'dtformat'`:

```
('dtformat', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'),
```